# SUM quantity based on 3 columns in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as shown here:

[image: table].

I need to sum the quantities for the same ITEM and LOC combinations for all dates in monthly buckets. 
For instance between 1-june and 30 june, I need to sum all quantities based on ITEM and LOC combinations.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the table into your question as text.  Links can grow stale, making the question non-sensical.  Sample results are also helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ITEM, LOC, YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date), SUM(Qty) Quantity
FROM Table
GROUP BY ITEM, LOC, YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
```

Comment: You're right, I've corrected my answer; by the way I still have some problems with the formatting of the answers ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(QTY),ITEM,LOC,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DATE,112) AS MONTH FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY ITEM,LOC,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),DATE,112)
```

Comment: The question is tagged for sql server. will your sql using `TO_CHAR` work on sql server?

Comment: Updated to use CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) instead of oracle equivalent TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')